R Shiny performance: generate plotly by function or download full html file?
So I am wondering the following:
In terms of speed of R Shiny taking into account a lot of users (say 100+) and using Shiny Server Open Source so on a single thread...what will be the fastest option showing a plotly html plot of roughly 2mb?

create a plotly html plot using a function  of roughly 100ms (measured by profvis).
download the full plotly html file from the server

I specifically wonder if calling a download function is the only thing that will need CPU-usage or that users need to wait before the full html file is downloaded by the first user before another user can do this.
